# AMPL: Subscript out of bound

Tags: ampl, neos-server

Hello fellow optimizers!

I'm having some issues with the following constraint:

```
#The supply at node i equals what was present at the last time period + any new supply and      subtracted by what has been extracted from the node.    
subject to Constraint1 {i in I, t in T, c in C}:
    l[i,t-1,c] + splus[i,t] - sum{j in J, v in V, a in A} x[i,j,v,t,c,a]= l[i,t,c];
```

which naturally causes this constraint to provide errors the first time it loops, as the t-1 is not defined (for me, l[i,0,c] is not defined. Where

```
  var l{I,T,C} >= 0;    # Supply at supply node I in time period T for company C.
  param splus{I,T};     # Additional supply at i.
  var x{N,N,V,T,C,A} integer >= 0;  #Flow from some origin within N to a destination within N using vehicle V, in time T, for company C and product A.
```

and set T; (in the .mod) is a set defined as:

```
 set T := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; in the .dat file
```

I've tried to do:

```
subject to Constraint1 {i in I, t in T: t >= 2, c in C}:
all else same
```

which got me a syntax error. I've also tried to include "let l[1,0,1] := 0" for all possible combinations, which got me the error

```
  error processing var l[...]:
  no data for set I
```

I've also tried

```
subject to Constraint1 {i in I, t in T, p in TT: p>t, c in C}:
   l[i,t,c] + splus[i,p] - sum{j in J, v in V, a in A} x[i,j,v,p,c,a]= l[i,p,c];
```

where

```
set TT := 2 3 4 5 6;
```

in the .dat file (and merely set TT; in the .mod) which also gave errors. Does someone have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to specify the condition `t >= 2` at the end of the indexing expression:

```
subject to Constraint1 {i in I, t in T, c in C: t >= 2}:
  ...
```

See also [Section A.3 Indexing expressions and subscripts](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/24-refman.pdf#page=3) for more details on syntax of indexing expressions.

Comment: Will try that tomorrow when I have my computer. Would be somewhat funny in a sense that I tried the same thing, but at a different place. Hehe. Thanks for your answer!